# save json as array in postgres db in django

Tags: arrays, json, django, database, postgresql

i got problem that i can't handle. i have a JSON file that include some hotel data such rooms, name, city and so on. some of this fields include more than one data and separate with " | " like this one :

```
  "image_urls": "//imghtlak.mmtcdn.com/images/hotels/201512081111224987/exterior.jpg|//imghtlak.mmtcdn.com/images/hotels/201512081111224987/room.jpg|//imghtlak.mmtcdn.com/images/hotels/201512081111224987/download.jpg",
```

or like this one:

```
   "highlight_value": "1 lift|24 hour business centre|24 hour coffee shop|24 hour reception|24 hour room service|24 hour security|24 hours front desk|24-hour business center|24-Hour Front Desk|24-hr Coffee Shop|24/7 Power|Activities desk|Activity centre|Airport Transfer Available With Charges Rs.200/- Per Trip|Arrangements Of Kitty Parties & Birthday Party|Auditorium|Ballroom|Banqueting|Bar|Board Room|Boardroom|Breakfast buffet|Children's Playground|Doctor on Call|Dry Cleaning|Dry Cleaning Service|Dry cleaning/laundry service|Free garage parking|Free Parking|Free Wi-Fi|Free Wi-Fi Icon|Handicap Facilities|Hot tub|In-room safe (some rooms)|Laundry Service|Newspaper|Non-smoking rooms|Room Service|Room service (24 hours)|Room Service (24 Hours)(after 11:00pm.round The Clock Menu)|Room Service 24 Hrs|Room Service 6 Am - 12 Night|Room Service 7 Am To 9 Pm|Room Service 7am-11:30pm|Room Service, 24 Hour Reception|Room Service, 24 Hour Reception And Laundry Service|Room Services 7 Am To 9 Pm|Wake up call|Wheelchair access"
```

and i want to separate them to save in postgres db as array and i have django project that my frontend colleague told me it should be array that he can use them and show them and i'm new in database i have no idea how to do that i mean how to make them array in one filed so he can use them and sort them.
sorry for bad english
by the way this is JSON file :
[This is full JSON file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sSYWuWNO00BilGmocGwu5Sf4ptoBpiro/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you can use something like this:

```
my_values = [
    {
        "highlight_value": "1 lift|24 hour business centre|24 hour coffee shop"
    }
]

new_items = []

for my_value in my_values:
    for values in my_value.values():
        if '|' in values:
            tokens = values.split('|')

            # REST OF CODE
```

Or, something like this:

```
elements = [
    values.split('|') 
        for my_value in my_values 
            for values in my_value.values() if '|' in values
]
```